# Connect Dell Boomi to SharePoint online as external content type

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-online, bcs, boomi, external-contenttype

I am trying to connect data from Dell Boomi to SharePoint online as an external content type through BCS. I have never worked on Dell Boomi before and there seems to be very little documentation available.

Can somebody please advice me on the best course of action to take if you have done something similar.

All I have is a webservice endpoint.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is you source data coming from? I am assuming you want to publish to SharePoint, right?

Comment: My source data is coming from Oracle db. I want to use it as an external list in SharePoint

Comment: I'm still looking into it. Reach out soon.

Comment: I'm a share point newbie, so the gist is to get data from your DB map it two a Profile accepted by SharePoint API use a connector of web service type to send it to share point. Any questions regarding the API can be taken to https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/
Hope it helps